# Using QT creator, how do I create a new screen?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

How can I create a new screen or page without creating a whole new window?

I would like to be able to use a push button that brings the user to a new area of the application.
A good example is in QT Creator itself how it has the "Edit" and "Design" buttons that bring the user to a new area of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Use [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html).

From the docs:

> The QStackedWidget class provides a stack of widgets where only one
>   widget is visible at a time.
>
> QStackedWidget can be used to create a user interface similar to the
>   one provided by QTabWidget. It is a convenience layout widget built on
>   top of the QStackedLayout class.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [QTabWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html). You can set different widget to show on every tab

Comment: I looked at QTabWidget and that is almost what I am looking for.  Using that I would still have the list of tabs across the top.  Is there something like that, that will create a fully new page?  And that hopefully can be triggered by a standard push button?